# How to get the multiple text from string in Android?

Tags: android, string, substring

I am developing the Android for Xively. I get the following text data and store into string.

```
{"id":111111177,"title":"G-sensor","private":"true","feed":"https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/111111177.json","auto_feed_url":"https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/111111177.json","status":"frozen","updated":"2014-08-05T07:14:29.783670Z","created":"2014-08-01T08:29:17.156043Z","creator":"https://xively.com/users/x22819","version":"1.0.0","datastreams":[{"id":"GPIO1","current_value":"1","at":"2014-08-05T07:14:18.991421Z","max_value":"1.0","min_value":"0.0","tags":["xyz"],"unit":{"type":"G","label":"watts"}},{"id":"GPIO2","current_value":"0","at":"2014-08-05T07:14:29.783670Z","max_value":"1.0","min_value":"0.0","tags":["xyz"],"unit":{"type":"G","label":"watts"}},{"id":"GPIO3","current_value":"1","at":"2014-08-05T06:51:08.165217Z","max_value":"1.0","min_value":"1.0"},{"id":"GPIO4","current_value":"0","at":"2014-08-05T06:51:13.029452Z","max_value":"0.0","min_value":"0.0"},{"id":"GPIO5","current_value":"1","at":"2014-08-05T06:51:20.679123Z","max_value":"1.0","min_value":"1.0"},{"id":"GPIO6","current_value":"0","at":"2014-08-05T06:51:27.057369Z","max_value":"0.0","min_value":"0.0"}],"location":{"domain":"physical"},"product_id":"w8tuBsYf835kYTjDFz9w","device_serial":"DWJAXD6N7VDZ"}
```

There has `id` and the `current_value` in the above data , and I want to get the data of `id` and the `current_value` from the above text like following text.

```
GPIO1 1
GPIO2 0
GPIO3 1
GPIO4 0
GPIO5 1
GPIO6 0
```

How do I capture the the data of `id` and the `current_value` from the above text ?
Can somebody teach me how to do ?

Thank in advance.

Comment: use gson lib for android

Comment: this ia called json and in andorid use json parsing in andorid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
String resultJSON = "datastreams":[{"id":"GPIO1","current_value":"1","at":"2014-08-05T07:14:18.991421Z","max_value":"1.0","min_value":"0.0","tags":["xyz"],"unit":{"type":"G","label":"watts"}},
{"id":"GPIO2","current_value":"0","at":"2014-08-05T07:14:29.783670Z","max_value":"1.0","min_value":"0.0","tags":["xyz"],"unit":{"type":"G","label":"watts"}},
{"id":"GPIO3","current_value":"1","at":"2014-08-05T06:51:08.165217Z","max_value":"1.0","min_value":"1.0"},
{"id":"GPIO4","current_value":"0","at":"2014-08-05T06:51:13.029452Z","max_value":"0.0","min_value":"0.0"},
{"id":"GPIO5","current_value":"1","at":"2014-08-05T06:51:20.679123Z","max_value":"1.0","min_value":"1.0"},
{"id":"GPIO6","current_value":"0","at":"2014-08-05T06:51:27.057369Z","max_value":"0.0","min_value":"0.0"}],"location":{"domain":"physical"},"product_id":"w8tuBsYf835kYTjDFz9w","device_serial":"DWJAXD6N7VDZ"};

    JSONObject jsonRoot  = new JSONObject(resultJSON);
    JSONArray  jsonData = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("Data");
    for(int i=0; i<jsonData.lenght;i++) {
        JSONObject jsonOBject = jsonData.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.d(TAG, "json ("+i+") = "+jsonOBject.toString());
        // do what you want with your JSONObject , i.e :add it to an ArrayList of paresed result
        String ID = jsonOBject.getString("id");

    }
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: Excuse me , it get the error :`W/System.err(17624): org.json.JSONException: No value for Data`.

Comment: its datastreams not data

Answer (score 1):

```
    dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

    // Getting JSON Array node
    myarray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("datastreams");

    // looping through All myarray
    for (int i = 0; i < myarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = myarray.getJSONObject(i);

    String id = c.getString("id");
    String date = c.getString("at");


    // tmp hashmap for single data
    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    data.put(TAG_ID, id);
    data.put(TAG_DATE, date);

    // adding data to data list
    dataList.add(data);
   }
```

Comment: Firstly when i post ur json here json.parser.online.fr it gives me syntax error ..plz check ur json syntax properly

Answer (score 1):

The data you have is actually a JSON so you can simply parse it to java POJO. I would suggest to use one of 2 most popular open source parsers [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

What you have to do is:

1. Create java POJOs for chosen parser. To make it easier use this online tool http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
2. Copy generated java classes to your project.
3. Use JSON parser e.g. GSON

Let's say you named your main class as Example, with GSON you can parse it like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String data = ....//your JSON data
Example example = gson.fromJson(data, Example.class);
```

Data you would like to get will have own Java representation and will be available through getter method, e.g.:

```
List<Datastream> datastreams = example.getDatastreamList();
for (DataStream data : datastreams) {
    String id = data.getId();
    String currentValue = data.getCurrentValue();
}
```

Then you can do whatever you like. Please know that GSON can also read streams, so if  you already parse stream to string you can skip it and pass that stream to Gson object directly.

If you don't want redundant POJOs or their parameters, you can remove them. GSON will handle it and simply ignore these values. Just make sure that data you are interested in keep the generated structure.

That's how I would do it.